# Error with google sign in button

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

So I have this code:
**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="MyApp" lang="en">
<head>
    <title ng-controller="MainController" ng-bind="organisation"></title>
    <link ng-controller="MainController" rel="icon" ng-href="{{ logo }}" />
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyD1mVN9oiWvgp6Zdp5e1pKOiLfdXNplcFo",
        authDomain: "testing-environment-98032.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://testing-environment-98032.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "testing-environment-98032.appspot.com",
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/index.css" />
</head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="initialize()">
        <div id="googleSignIn" ng-style="googleSignInStyle" ng-click="signUserIn()" ng-bind="googleSignInText"></div>
        <span ng-click="signOut()" >Sign Out!</span>
        <article id="scrollSpeedValue" class="valuePasser"><?php echo $scrollSpeed; ?></article>
        <div id="h1-margin">&nbsp;</div>
        <center><span class="h1"><b ng-bind="organisation"></b></span></center>
        <div class="main">
            <span ng-bind-html="generateNavBar(navBar.common, navBar.common[0])"></span>
            <marquee id="EventsMarquee" class="infoBanner" direction="left" scrollamount="10">Events here! Set initial speed to 1000000000</marquee>
            <div class="main-body" id="main-body">
                <center><i>Welcome to the -- site!</i></center><br>
                <div style="width: 48%; float: left;">
                    Description
                </div>
                <div style="width: 48%; float: right;"><iframe src="http://www.google.com" style="width: 99%; height: 373px;"></iframe></div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-body" id="footer-links">
                <center>
                    <a href="#" title="Resources">Resources</a> | <a href="#" title="organisation Resources">organisation Resources</a> | <a href="#" title="link">link</a> | <a href="editable.php" title="Edit!">Edit!</a>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <br>
        </footer>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function ($scope){
    $scope.organisation = "Organisation Name";
    $scope.logo = "http://www.weboniks.com/images/logos/logo5.jpg";
    $scope.googleSignInStyle = {};
    $scope.googleSignInText = "";
    $scope.signInVariables = {
        displayName: null,
        email: null,
        uid: null,
        photoURL: null
    }
    $scope.navBar = {
        common: [
            ["Home", "index.html"],
            ["Resources", "index.html"],
            ["Staff Resources", "index.html"],
            [$scope.organisation + " Resources", "index.html"],
            ["Who we are", "index.html"]
        ]
    }
    $scope.signIn = function (){
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;
            var providerData = user.providerData[0];

            firebase.database().ref('users/' + providerData.displayName).set({Email: providerData.email, PhotoURL: providerData.photoURL, uid: providerData.uid});

        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            var email = error.email;
            var credential = error.credential;
            console.log ("Error! Error code: " + errorCode + ", Email: " + email + ", Credential: " + credential + ". That's all we know.");
        });
    }
    $scope.onSignIn = function (){
        var providerData = firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0];
        if (providerData.photoURL == null)
        {
            $scope.googleSignInStyle["background"] = "url(../images/img_default_profile.png)";
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.googleSignInStyle["background"] = providerData.photoURL;
        }

        $scope.googleSignInStyle["background-size"] = "100%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["border-radius"] = "100%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["width"] = "4.5%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["height"] = "9%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["cursor"] = "default";
    }
    $scope.checkSignIn = function (){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            setTimeout(function (){ $scope.checkSignIn(); }, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.onSignIn();
        }
    }
    $scope.signUserIn = function (){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            $scope.signIn();
            setTimeout(function (){ $scope.checkSignIn() }, 10000);
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.onSignIn();
        }
    }
    $scope.signOut = function (){
        firebase.auth().signOut();
        $scope.googleSignInText = "";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["background"] = "url(../images/btn_google_signin_dark_normal_web@2x.png)";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["background-size"] = "100%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["border-radius"] = "0%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["width"] = "12%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["height"] = "6%";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["cursor"] = "default";
        $scope.googleSignInStyle["cursor"] = "pointer";
    }
    $scope.generateNavBar = function (items, current){
        var navigator = '<nav><ul><b>';
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i] == current)
            {
                navigator += '<a href="' + items[i][1] + '"><li id="current">' + items[i][0] + '</li></a>';
            }
            else
            {
                navigator += '<a href="' + items[i][1] + '"><li>' + items[i][0] + '</li></a>';
            }
        }

        navigator += '</b></ul></nav>';

        console.log (navigator);
        return navigator;
    }
}]);
```

This code is supposed to sign a user in with google and then change the sign in with google button to their profile image. It works fine, the only issue is that the first time you click the sign in button it only signs you in. Then you have to click it again to change the button to the users image. Is there something I have done wrong?

Comment: Difficult to tell what's wrong with it without a Plunkr but try adding a `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the `onSignIn` function. Sometimes Angular needs to be told to run a digest cycle when it doesn't realise it needs to update the front end.

Comment: Thank you very much! That saved us a lot work!!